# schengen visa issued by French consulate in South Africa - free movement to Switzerland?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, switzerland, south-african-citizens

I am in France on a schengen tourism visa on my South African passport. My plans when I applied for the visa were to visit france, Germany and the Czech republic. Is there any reason why I would not be allowed to make an adjustment to my itinerary now that I am here and make a side trip to Switzerland on this visa? The reason for this is to break up a long train trip between Germany and France.

Family of mine say that they had problems because they required schengen and a separate visa for Switzerland. This seems contradictory to the schengen idea of free movement and everything else I've read. Just in case, can anyone confirm this for me?

Comment: It's fine to visit Switzerland.  The problem your family had could have been a lot of things but all things being equal there is nothing preventing you from a side trip.

Comment: Were your family members traveling before Switzerland joined the Schengen area, perhaps?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Switzerland joined on 12 December 2008.